# How can I add a style to an input field along with the required attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently if an input field with the `required` attribute is empty, it will display the browser's default error message. If I remove this attribute, it will display a red border on the input field because of my JavaScript code. How would I display both at the same time?

```js
function validate() {
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  if (!title.value) {
    title.classList.add('error');
    setTimeout(function() {
      title.classList.remove('error');
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="text" id="title" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```